# Math question partial derivatives help?

Tags: derivatives

I have the functions : $u=\arctan(xyz)$ where $x=\cos(t)\quad  y=e^t$ and $z=1/t$.
I have to find $\dfrac{du}{dt}$.
My attempt to a solution : $\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\dfrac{dz}{dt}$
$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{yz}{1+x^2\cdot y^2\cdot z^2}$ ;$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{-\sin t \partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac{xz}{1+x^2\cdot y^2\cdot z^2}$ ,$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=e^t$ ,
$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\dfrac{xy}{1+x^2\cdot y^2 \cdot z^2}$ $\dfrac{dz}{dt}=\dfrac{-1}{t^2}$.
The problem is,how do I replace these back into the formula so I could get a result : 
$\dfrac{e^t(t\cos t-t\sin t+\cos t)}{t^2+e^{(2t)} \cdot \cos^2(t)}$

I SOLVED THIS,THANK YOU ALREADY.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to write problems using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: If someone can edit this for me,until I learn how to edit properly,I will be very grateful :)

Comment: FYI: when you receive answers that are helpful, you may *accept* one answer per question. You can accept an answer by clicking on the "$\large \checkmark$" symbol located to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Plus, you get two reputation points for every answer you accept.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right. There are two ways to finish this:
1) Continue from what you got: replace $x,y,z$ by the functions of $t$ and get the common denumerator.
2) Write $U(t)=\arctan(xyz)=\arctan\left(\frac{e^t\cos t}t\right)$. Now just compute the derivative.

Comment: No,I need this with the first one,but when I replace what I got,I dont get it right :/

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the chain rule as follows:

$xyz=f(t)=\cos(t)t^{-1}e^t$

$(\frac{d}{dt}U(f(t)))=(\frac{d}{df}U(f))(\frac{d}{dt}f(t))$

${\frac {d}{df}}U \left( f \right) ={\frac {d}{df}}\arctan \left( f \right)= \left( 1+{f}^{2} \right) ^{-1}$

${\frac {d}{dt}}f \left( t \right) =(-{\frac {\sin \left( t \right) }{t}
}+{\frac {\cos \left( t \right) }{t}}-{\frac {\cos \left( t \right) }{
{t}^{2}}}
)e^{t}$    ...use product rule here.

${\frac {d}{dt}}U \left( t \right) =-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{t}} \left( \sin
 \left( t \right) t-\cos \left( t \right) t+\cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) }{{t}^{2}+ \left( \cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}{{\rm e}
^{2\,t}}}}
$